# Quick explanation, what is code behind $ in regards to x and y? (very short example using AutoIt)

Tags: xcode

Being new to programming, AutoIt using Imagesearch

```
$result = _ImageSearch("flowr.png",1,$x1,$y1,100)
```

having saved the desired imagine, what does

1. the 1 after the image-name mean?
2. (1 click)  $x1 and $y1 mean
3. (coordinates for that 1x click)  the 100 the speed?

The line of code began with

```
#include <ImageSearch.au3>
$x1=0
$y1=0
```

what is the $x1=0 here?

I'd love to just use google and type in "what does $x1=0 mean" but the translation of it yields a completely different answer and has nothing to do with coding^^

Thank you very much for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

The 1 after the flowername seems to be the tolerance, a value from 0-255 according to this documentation I found [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148005-imagesearch-usage-explanation/)

```
; Description:   Find the position of an image on the desktop
; Syntax:        _ImageSearchArea, _ImageSearch
; Parameter(s):
;                $findImage - the image to locate on the desktop
;                $tolerance - 0 for no tolerance (0-255). Needed when colors of
;                            image differ from desktop. e.g GIF
;                $resultPosition - Set where the returned x,y location of the image is.
;                                    1 for centre of image, 0 for top left of image
;                $x $y - Return the x and y location of the image
;
; Return Value(s): On Success - Returns 1
;                On Failure - Returns 0
```

The lines like `$x1 = 0` are simple assignment operations.  You are saving the value `0` in the variable `$x1`.  You can later add, subtract, multiply, etc. using that value or store some other calculation which makes your program easy to alter.

You should try some examples to get the basics of programming down before diving in to an image search program.  If all else fails though you can always check the [Documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/).